# FirebaseShutdown Fatal Exception

Tags: ios, firebase, google-api

I have an iOS app in which I use Google's Sign In SDK & Google's Directions API.

Suddenly, since a couple of hours, I've had a huge amount of crashes of the following type:

```
Fatal Exception: FirebaseShutdown
Specified Firebase database has reached its Peak Connections limit. If you are the Firebase owner, consider upgrading.
```

I have absolutely no idea where this has come from -- there hasn't been a sudden rise in connections. I've gone to the Google Console Log and I see no errors there. I have absolutely no direct call to Firebase in my code, so I have no idea where this comes from.

What could the cause be? How can I prevent this fast?

Comment: When you state 'I have absolutely no direct call to Firebase in my code', does that mean you are not using Firebase to store any data and there are no Firebase functions in your code like Observe or Query?

Comment: *firebaser here* Please [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/), where they can provide personalized support with troubleshooting this issue.

Comment: @Jay Yes, that's what it means. There might be a third party framework making calls, but I'm not making them directly... i have contacted Firebase support about this too, I was just wondering if someone had ever had this.